# Is it possible to use VSCode to create a Webbased IDE

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, ide, cloud

I know about other such projects e.g. Theia which are based on Monaco editor similar to VSCode as well. However, does MSFT provide a way to use VSCode itself while developing a web based IDE?

Answer (score 0):

This is also an example of something similar

https://github.com/cdr/code-server

Comment: Thank you @HPKG. I did come across it. I will try to reverse engineer but this repo doesn't explain what is needed to convert VSCode from sources to a web based editor. I would like to learn that and create my own web-based editor from VSCode sources.